# How to modify the bit_rate of AVFormatContext?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, bitrate

Hello，I would like to know how to modify the bit_rate of AVFormatContext.

Here is the minimal reproducible example.This is a simple process for pushing rtmp video streams.Now I want to control the bitrate of the video it pushes.

I tried modifying the bitrate like this, but it didn't work.

```
AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL, *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
int64_t bit_rate = 400*1000;
....
ofmt_ctx->bit_rate = bit_rate;
```

Can be compiled by `g++ -Wall -o -g -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib  simplt_push_streaming.cpp -o test.out -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpthread`

And my ffmpeg version: `ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1`

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"
{
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AVOutputFormat *ofmt = NULL;
    //Input AVFormatContext and Output AVFormatContext
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL, *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    AVPacket pkt;
    const char *in_filename, *out_filename;
    int ret, i;
    int videoindex=-1;
    int frame_index=0;
    int64_t start_time=0;
    int64_t bit_rate = 400*1000;
    in_filename  = "/home/zion/video/mecha.flv";// Input file URL
    out_filename = "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/test";//Output URL [RTMP]
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_filename, 0, 0);
    avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0);
    for(i=0; i<ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) 
        if(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
            videoindex=i;
            break;
        }
    //Output
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, "flv", out_filename); //RTMP
    ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        //Create output AVStream according to input AVStream
        AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
        //Copy the settings of AVCodecContext
        ret = avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec);
        out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
        if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            out_stream->codec->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
    //Open output URL
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    }
    //Write file header
    avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    start_time=av_gettime();
    while (1) {
        AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;
        //Get an AVPacket
        ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        //Important:Delay
        if(pkt.stream_index==videoindex){
            AVRational time_base=ifmt_ctx->streams[videoindex]->time_base;
            AVRational time_base_q={1,AV_TIME_BASE};
            int64_t pts_time = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, time_base, time_base_q);
            int64_t now_time = av_gettime() - start_time;
            if (pts_time > now_time)
                av_usleep(pts_time - now_time);
        }
        in_stream  = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        if(pkt.stream_index==videoindex){
            printf("Send %8d video frames to output URL\n",frame_index);
            frame_index++;
        }
/*I tried modifying the bitrate here and I'm not sure if this is the correct usage.*/
        ofmt_ctx->bit_rate = bit_rate;
        av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt);
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }
    //Write file trailer
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    /* close output */
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_close(ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `ofmt_ctx` null? You'll need to allocate it before you try to modify it. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please show a [mre]

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFormatContext.html#a972a02b9e3b542a426e323a8f8e3ea41 - never set bit rate directly.

Comment: @kiner_shah make sure to read the whole statement `Never set it directly if the file_size and the duration are known as FFmpeg can compute it automatically.`. it doesn't say never set it, it says (slightly poorly worded) that if you know the duration and target file size the bitrate shouldn't be set as it'll be calculated, otherwise you can set the bitrate

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yeah right, poorly worded.

Comment: @Alan Birtles I have allocate it by ```avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, "flv", out_filename); ```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't change the bitrate miss stream, it'll need to be set before starting the stream [`reconfig_encoder`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libx264_8c.html#ab233cd9682658de5a947d67492264672) might work?